# Monitoring CPU and temperature

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, temperature

I'm looking for some interfaces to monitor the use of the CPU and the temperature, i have already installed `lm-sensors` for temp and `htop` for CPU but i want something that shows them always in real-time in the bar at the top of the screen (the one which says time, battery% ecc.. sorry i don't know how it is called) so that i shouldn't always run the mentioned command from the terminal. I have Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Conky might be of interest, but it displays the information on the desktop, not on the top tool bar. Guide for installing on Ubuntu 16.04:
 http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/what-is-conky-and-how-to-configure-conky-on-ubuntu-1604

Comment: I'd like the mentioned infos in the top tool bar so that i could monitor my programs running on the terminal with just one of them opened and not 3, with Conky i'll have only 2 displays which would be better of 3 but still i'd prefer not having them at all, if i don't find anything for the purpose i'll give it a try @VassilisPapanikolaou

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The software is called psensor.

- Linux: https://wpitchoune.net/psensor/
- Specific for Ubuntu: https://wpitchoune.net/psensor/ubuntu.html

There is an option to display the info on the toolbar, as well as in a stand-alone window.

Answer (score 8):

This is a quick-and-dirty way I use to monitor my system core temperatures.

- install lm-sensors (if available in repository and can read CPU / GPU temps on respective hardware.
- install watch

`watch` repeatedly executes the following command until exited.  By default, it refreshes every 2 seconds, but this can be changed using "-n " switch.

In a console window or on cli, execute

- `watch sensors` shows temps, refreshes every 2 seconds
- `watch -n 5 sensors` shows temps, refreshes every 5 seconds

My output shows:

```
Every 5.0s: sensors              HOST-NAME: Wed Apr 15 08:13:57 2020

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +45.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +45.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +45.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:        +44.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:        +44.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Comment: On fedora 35, the package can be installed with `yum install lm_sensors`

Answer (score 1):

With psensor and real time measurement you need to be careful. I tried the program and I could hear by the fan of my laptop that the system-load created by psensor heated up the CPU non-negligibly. Somehow it prevented the CPU from idling.
Now, with psensor de-installed the fan is less active. As the program only measures the temperatures and does not control the fan, at the same noise level the system should be cooler without psensor.

Comment: Are there any real time measurement tools which also  control the fan?

Comment: I know there is speedfan, but it runs on windows. I have never tested it with wine.

Answer (score 0):

There are ultilitys in lm_sensors, its all a bit non-intuitive,,
fancontrol 1st, then pwmconfig

Answer (score 0):

I personally use **system monitor extension** for **Gnome** since it's an inbuilt piece of software and doesn't consume too much resources in order to provide hardware information and is a **widget** on the top panel.

It's also highly customizable so you can set refresh rate per the separate components like cpu, ram, disk, network, etc It also has swap, fan and battery options.

[image]
This is my widget on **Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS** with **Unity**, it's configured only to keep in track RAM and Disk read/writes, but you can **customize it as you wish**, as seen below in the **preferences panel**
[image]

Here you can find more information on how to install and use it [**http://ubuntuhandbook.org**](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/03/display-cpu-memory-network-usage-in-ubuntu-18-04-panel/)